# Working with the frontmost window's controls in a document-based app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, document-based

I've scanned the documentation and googled fairly extensively and found nothing on this subject.

What I'm needing to do is interact with a specific instance of one of my NSWindows - that is, one created through the NSDocument system put in place by creating a document-based application in Xcode.

So is there a way to do this? Something like [[NSSharedDocumentController frontmostWindow] subView: doAction], perhaps?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? If your application has five documents opened, which one are you interested in? Does your application have windows other than the document windows? Do your `NSDocument` subclass manage its own window controllers?

Comment: It's nothing more than the default doc-based setup. All I'm interested in at this point is the frontmost window and/or the in the case of programmatcally creating a new document, the window I just created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the frontmost window (aka the main window), use `-[NSApplication mainWindow]`:

```
NSWindow *mainWindow = [NSApp mainWindow];
```

To obtain the window corresponding to a given document:

```
NSDocument *someDocument; // reference to the document you’re interested in
NSWindow *window = [[[someDocument windowControllers] objectAtIndex:0] window];
```

`NSDocument` creates a single window controller to manage the corresponding document window, so `-[NSDocument windowControllers]` returns an array with a single element corresponding to the window controller. `-[NSWindowController window]` returns the window managed by that window controller.